# .htaccess showing 500 internal error in subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, kohana

This is the htaccess code i m using to redirect, please suggest good solution i m using this previously same as another server but when i have changed hosting the i m getting this error

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@payments.boutiquemerchantsolutions.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
#RewriteBase /

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(application|modules|system) - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
#RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [PT,L]
RewriteRule .* index.php?kohana_uri=$0 [PT,QSA,L]
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting! (Format as a "code block", not a "quotation") I had a go, but you seem to be missing line breaks in important places - so I don't know if I'm actually changing/fixing the code? Also, please explain your problem better... what URL are you requesting. Check your error log for more details of the error.

Comment: [link](https://payments.boutiquemerchantsolutions.com/) @user82217

Comment: You didn't post the error.

Comment: did that now..@m-abshir